# iPhone 6 to macbook pro wireless debugging without cable

Tags: iphone, xcode, debugging

I have MacBook Pro (13-inch, 2017, Two Thunderbolt 3 ports) with high sierra (Version 10.13.4) and iPhone 6 with iOS version 11.2.5.

I don't have any kind of cable through which I connect my iPhone to my MacBook Pro. 
I want to enable wireless debugging in iPhone because I don't have cable.

Can anyone suggest me how I can enable wireless debugging in xcode and run my application on device without the need of creating diawi link on each time and on each change.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I don't have cable. Can you please suggest any other way for it.

Answer (score 0):

You have to plug the device in one time, the first time, to establish the feature under `Devices and Simulators`. After that, you can use the wireless debugging, but it does require that first wired connection.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I don't have cable. Can you please suggest any other way for it.

Comment: Without the first time connection, there is no other way that I know of.